# I am getting a file not found error when trying to read a csv file using pandas. I am sure I have used the correct path to the file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I am trying to read a CSV file using pandas read_csv function but I keep getting a file not found error. Here is the code I used and although I said I am sure I have used the correct path I could still be wrong, please point errors out to me if that is the case. Please note I am using Jupyter Notebook as part of Anaconda.

```
import pandas as pd

melbourne_file_path = 'Downloads\melb_data.csv'
melbourne_data = pd.read_csv(melbourne_file_path) 
print(melbourne_data.describe())
```

The error I get is

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-f31a03883307> in <module>()
  2 
  3 melbourne_file_path = 'Downloads\melb_data.csv'    
----> 4 melbourne_data = pd.read_csv(melbourne_file_path)
  5 print(melbourne_data.describe())

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    707                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    708 
--> 709         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    710 
    711     parser_f.__name__ = name

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    447 
    448     # Create the parser.
--> 449     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    450 
    451     if chunksize or iterator:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    816             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    817 
--> 818         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    819 
    820     def close(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1047     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
   1048         if engine == 'c':
-> 1049             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1050         else:
   1051             if engine == 'python':

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1693         kwds['allow_leading_cols'] = self.index_col is not False
   1694 
-> 1695         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1696 
   1697         # XXX

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: File b'Downloads\\melb_data.csv' does not exist
```

Any help is appreciated.

As requested here is the error I receive.

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d428ae69b6da> in <module>()
      2 
      3 melbourne_file_path = 'C:/Users/Username/Downloads'
----> 4 melbourne_data = pd.read_csv(melbourne_file_path)
      5 print(melbourne_data.describe())

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in 
parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, 
usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, 
true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, 
keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, 
infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, 
chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, 
quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, 
error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, 
delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, 
buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    707                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    708 
--> 709         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    710 
    711     parser_f.__name__ = name

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in 
_read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    447 
    448     # Create the parser.
--> 449     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    450  
    451     if chunksize or iterator:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, 
engine, **kwds)
    816             self.options['has_index_names'] = 
kwds['has_index_names']
    817 
--> 818         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    819 
    820     def close(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, 
engine)
   1047     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
   1048         if engine == 'c':
-> 1049             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1050         else:
   1051             if engine == 'python':

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, 
**kwds)
   1693         kwds['allow_leading_cols'] = self.index_col is not False
   1694 
-> 1695         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1696 
   1697         # XXX

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in 
pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

OSError: Initializing from file failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full path instead of relative path. You are referencing `'Downloads\melb_data.csv'` but it could be that your current directory is not what you think it is, especially when running from Juypter. Try something like `~/Downloads/melb_data.csv`

Comment: I have used the format you suggested and now have got an OS error. Would you like me to show the full error?

Comment: What OS are you using? and what would be the full path to your Downloads folder?

Comment: Windows 10 is the OS and the full path is C:\Users\Username\Downloads

Comment: Try to do "C:/Users/Username/Downloads" and see if that works - if not post the error message

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from the backslash in the path to the file.

With python, you can always use forward-slash ("/") and it will be translated on windows systems.

`'C:/mydir'`

Or you could try the following:

`'C:\\mydir'`

The best solution though is probably to use the `os` package to correctly choose what's best for your system

Comment: I have used the OS package to find the file path I need and input it but I get an OS error. I have edited the error into the original post.